# Find the smallest 4 points of data using python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, signals

I have data in a text files contain two columns x and y. I know that this data have 4 extreme minimum local points.

I used this code to get them. The problem is that my code gives me all minimum point which are 23 point and can't define the extreme minimum point as shown as in the attached figure

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Path = "input/*.txt"
input_files = glob.glob(Path)
for file_name in input_files:   
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, delimiter="\t")
    x = df[0]
    y = df[1] 
  
    minima_indices = argrelextrema(np.array(y), np.less)[0]

    minima_x = x[minima_indices]
    minima_y = y[minima_indices] 


    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.plot(minima_x,minima_y, "x",markersize = 5)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNhDr.png)

My target is to mark the 4 extreme minimum points and save them as a text file. Could you help me please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I modified my question. My target is to mark the 4 extreme minimum points and save them as a text file.